# node.js issue: invalid buffer causing preloaded files to not load

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm building a website off of an open source github repo, and while I did not change the website details, the site contains preloaded .txt files that somehow come out blank when opening them. When I open the repo in Git, the preloaded text comes out fine, but not when the site is published into github pages. The error I get is as follows:

> `Uncaught Error: Invalid buffer: Buffer is 2621 long, yet Stats object specifies that file is 1134 long. at OverlayFile.PreloadFile [as constructor] (preload_file.ts:57:13) at new OverlayFile (OverlayFS.ts:35:10) at OverlayFS.ts:421:27 at XmlHttpRequest.ts:373:18 at NoSyncFile.close (preload_file.ts:404:5) at cb (XmlHttpRequest.ts:369:13) at XmlHttpRequest.ts:379:9 at XmlHttpRequest.ts:290:20 at req.onreadystatechange (xhr.ts:44:20)`

when I check `preload_file.ts` it doesn't seem like anything is wrong? Although this is the line of concern:

`if (this._stat.size !== this._buffer.length && this._flag.isReadable()) { throw new Error(`Invalid buffer: Buffer is ${this._buffer.length} long, yet Stats object specifies that file is ${this._stat.size} long.`); }`

I'm not entirely sure what the issue is. If anyone could help me understand what this error means I would really appreciate it, as well if anyone needs more info on the code.

I'm building a website off of an open source github repo, and while I did not change the website details, the site contains preloaded .txt files that somehow come out blank when opening them. When I open the repo in Git, the preloaded text comes out fine, but not when the site is published into github pages. The error I get is as follows:

I'm not entirely sure what the issue is. If anyone could help me understand what this error means I would really appreciate it, as well if anyone needs more info on the code.

I haven't tried anything yet because I am confused on the error to begin with.